# Jquery for dialog in MVC4

Tags: jquery-ui

I used jquery ui from this  link http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#animated for dialog which is not working in MVC4 application

This is my View
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Dialog";

```
}
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="../../Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    // increase the default animation speed to exaggerate the effect
    $.fx.speeds._default = 1000;
    $(function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            show: "blind",
            hide: "explode"
        });

        $("#opener").click(function () {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="demo">
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p>
            This is an animated dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog
            window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
    </div>
    <button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
</div>
<!-- End demo -->
<div class="demo-description">
    <p>
        Dialogs may be animated by specifying an effect for the show and/or hide properties.
        You must include the individual effects file for any effects you would like to use.</p>
</div>
<!-- End demo-description -->
<div class="demo-description">
    <p>
        A modal dialog prevents the user from interacting with the rest of the page until
        it is closed.</p>
</div>
<!-- End demo-description -->
```

Comment: can you post some code, or give some more information as to how and why this isn't working for you?

Comment: The jquery Ui code for dialog is in that link

Comment: we need to know how you are trying to use the code in that link.  I can pretty much guarantee that the code in that link is good, so we need to know how you are using it.

Comment: I gave the code which i used above http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11560393/jquery-for-dialog-in-mvc4

Comment: I used the code given in that code with some scripts added which are required

Comment: But still when i click on button i am not getting any dialog box

Answer (score 0):

You're not wiring up your javascript.  Try this:

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
     autoOpen: false,
     show: "blind",
     hide: "explode"
});

$(document).ready(function(){
     $('#opener').click(function () {
          $('#dialog').dialog("open");
          return false;
     });
});
```

(remove the opening "`$(function () {`" and the closing "`});`" pair to this - your code wants to look like above.

Comment: take a look at this jsfiddle, see if it helps you... http://jsfiddle.net/NucBs/1/

Comment: Should i add any extra scripts from MVC4 because the code which i used is working in jfiddle

Comment: take a look at the resulting html/javascript code that gets sent to the browser, this might help you.  Sorry I gave you a wrong steer before.

Comment: k i got my version of RC was not supporting jquery pop up dialog

Comment: that's good - is that what the problem was?  Is the pop up dialog coming up now?

Answer (score 0):

Add      `$(documnet).ready` and then define your function in it . . ..

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    code goes here  . . 
    });`
```